# Bootstrap list group for desktop, accordion for mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items in my footer. For desktop I'd like it to just be a simple list group. For mobile, I want just the titles to show but the actual list items should be collapsed in an accordion. Is there a way to do that or do I need to create two separate versions, one for mobile and one for desktop?

[image]

Comment: You're probably best with two separate versions, setting the [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) for visibility at their respective breakpoints. I'm sure there are those that would disagree, but I think it comes down to how similar/different each version will be from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by doing using a collapsible list-group and a script to show it collapsed for mobile but expanded for desktop.

http://www.bootply.com/cTsrC18csm

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must use two codes

Because you are using  bootstrap accordion and it have many selector such as id="accordion" role="tablist" , data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" and etc

You must separate you codes

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion